# Logrotate encryption before mailing

Tags: email, logging, smtp, pgp, logrotate

I use logrotate that sends me logs on a regular basis. My server is a VPS running Postfix as an outgoing-only SMTP server.

I would like all the mailed logs (which Logrotate sends) to be encrypted with PGP or S/MIME. How can I do that?

I searched for logrotate mail encryption, but couldn't find any. Therefore, I'm thinking that I can pass "nomail" command in logrotate config, but then add in the "postscript" a script to first encrypt the mail and then send.

So, is there a better way to encypt logrotate mail with PGP? Or that's what I need to do? I would appreciate any advise or an example of such a script.

Also, I'm not considering to use TLS as there are possible ways to bypass it in the SMTP server. And I would rather rely on encryption of individual messages.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is my script I'm using for custom email sending(Without GPG for now):

```
#!/bin/bash
read MSG
echo $MSG | mail -s $1 $2
```

But when I force rotate with `logrotate --mail=loggpg.sh --force /etc/logrotate.d/ufw` I keep getting error about uncompression, do I need to manually uncompress it? Or there is smth wrong with the script?

Error I get:

```
error: mail command failed for /var/log/ufw.log.5.gz
error: uncompress command failed mailing /var/log/ufw.log.5.gz`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute logrotate with `--mail` command line option. It will allow you to use your own shell/perl/python script to send email instead of default `/bin/mail -s`.

man logrotate

> **OPTIONS**
>   ...
>    **-m, --mail** 
>                 Tells logrotate which command to use when mailing logs. This command should accept two arguments: 1) the subject of the message, and
>                 2)  the  recipient. The command must then read a message on standard input and mail it to the recipient. The default mail command is
>                 /bin/mail -s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try now make a script and will update once I succeed.

Comment: Hey, I've tried to make a shell script and call it without gpg first, just to make sure it works and send mail. However I keep getting error. I've updated my question with what I have. Would appreciate if you can tell me what's wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `read MSG ; echo $MSG | mail -s $1 $2` try `mail -s "$1" "$2"`